# WP-load and Dompdf error

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I've correctly included `wp-load.php` and dompdf but there seems to be conflict.  I get this error

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in
>   /home/sites/example.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/dompdf/www/showpdf.php
>   on line 16

If i remove the wp-load.php, then dompdf correctly shows the pdf file.  I need wp-load.php to use wordpress functions.

Here is my code.

```
<?
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php');
 require_once("../dompdf_config.inc.php");


 $id = $_GET['id']; //requested recipe ID

  ob_start(); // begin buffering PDF content

 echo "test";
 $html = ob_get_clean();  // grab buffered content and stop buffering

  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $filename = $id.".pdf";
  $dompdf->stream($filename,array('Attachment'=>0)); //opens pdf in new tab
?>
```

why do i get this error when i include wp-load.php?

Comment: Which version of dompdf are you using? The autoloader in v0.5.x wasn't compatible with other autoloaders, so make sure you're using v0.6.x. You could also try reversing the order of the require statements. It's possible the WP autoloader will play nicer.

Comment: i ended up using mpdf.